# Push checked value of checkbox and pop unchecked value in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

Sorry if this is a very silly question but I am stuck and unable to find any solution.

I am generating checkboxes dynamically using map function and I want to push some value when the checkbox is checked and pop that value if the checkbox is unchecked.

```
this.state.invoices.map((inv,i)=>{
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked=??? className="floatright" onClick={()=>{this.childCheckfunc(inv)}}/>
```

I am getting some value in childCheckfunc() and I want to know how do I manage the property of checkbox to get the checked value so that I can push it in an array and pop if unchecked.

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `event` object also to your function

```
onClick={(e)=>{this.childCheckfunc(inv, e)}}
```

and then you can access checked property like this.

```
childCheckfunc(inv, event) {
 const cheked  = event.target.checked
}
```

Comment: It did the work.. Thank you :) Was missing something very basic :) Thanks for your help